# Toggle image display using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This code should display 2 buttons `Map` & `Rainfall`.
Above that should be the text `"Choose a display"`.
Once either button is clicked, it then displays either a google map image (If map button clicked) or a Rainfall image (If rainfall button clicked).

The issue I'm having is if I click the map button first, the text is swapped for the map, which is great, but then if I click the rainfall button, the image doesn't replace the map, it just displays under it.

Also if I click the rainfall button BEFORE the map button with the text displayed, then the image is displayed UNDER the text `"Choose a display"` when I want it to be hidden after I click that button too.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<p align="center"style="font-family:verdana;"id="googlemap">Choose a Main Display</p>
<p align="center"id="bommap"></p>

<p align="center">
    <button type="button" onclick="mapFunction()">Map</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="rainFunction()">Rainfall</button>
</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function mapFunction() {
    x = document.getElementById("googlemap"); // Find the element
    x.innerHTML = '<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com.au/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=23+Burgundy+St,+Carseldine+QLD&amp;daddr=90+Gilbert+Rd,+Grange+QLD+to:Narrowneck+Court+Surfers+Paradise,+204+Ferny+Ave,+Surfers+Paradise+QLD&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FfOeXv4d6qweCSn9XcBQSP2TazGVQ_0hH3aSYA%3BFRKQXf4d5_QeCSlRy4j_0lmRazEdtrkd8CRD0Q%3BFWXtVP4dWCUlCSGK90q-pKXOZCmv-18SewWRazGK90q-pKXOZA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Narr&amp;sll=-27.422699,153.02411&amp;sspn=0.004819,0.008272&amp;t=h&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-27.555764,153.208466&amp;spn=0.584401,0.878906&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"></iframe>' // Change the content
}

function rainFunction() {
    x = document.getElementById("bommap"); // Find the Element
    x.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR663.gif?20130517070843" border="0" alt="128 km Brisbane (Mt Stapylton) Radar" title="128 km Brisbane (Mt Stapylton) Radar">'
}
```

Comment: thats because your are adding the content to 2 different elements

Comment: Just set all values in `x=document.getElementById("value")` to `googlemap` (e.g. `x=document.getElementById("googlemap")`, and remove the `<p align="center"id="bommap"></p>`. That should fix your problem. Regarding optimalisation, there are certain things you could do to write code that is more re-usable/open for extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a separate `p` for the rainmap and the google map so when your functions run and show the content by changing their `innerHTML` both maps will show. For your example to work you'd have to do the following

```
function rainFunction()
{
  var x=document.getElementById("bommap");    // Find the Element
  var x.innerHTML='<img src="http://www.bom.etc.etc.' //Change the content
  document.getElementById("googlemap").innerHTML = ''; //Empty the googlemap content;
}
```

When your function runs now it will empty (remove) the content of the other `P` element. You need to apply this logic to your other function as well for this to work. You should also declare your local variables with the `var` keyword.

You can combine this into one function something like this.

```
function changeImages(ele){

   var x = document.getElementById("bommap");
   var y = document.getElementById("googlemap");
   var z = document.getElementById("weather"); // ID of the new weather p element

   if(ele === y.id){ //if the value we passed into the function is the same as the p id  
      x.innerHTML = ''; //Empty rainforest image
      z.innerHTML = ''; //Empty the weather image
      y.innerHTML = '<iframe width="640" height="480" etc' //Set googlemap content
   } else if(ele === x.id) {
      y.innerHTML = '';  //Empty googleMap
      z.innerHTML = ''   //Empty weather
      x.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.bom.gov.au/radar/ etc' //Set bommap content
   } else {
      y.innerHTML = '' //Empty googleMap
      x.innerHTML = '' //Empty bommap
      z.innerHTML = 'contenct for weather here' //Set weather content
   }
}
```

Then call this function from either of your buttons

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeImages('googlemap')">Map</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeImages('bommap')">Rainfall</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeImages('weather')">Weather</button>
```

It may be much more efficient to show/hide your images/elements rather than setting their content dynamically. Please google show/hide with javascript. The basic idea would be to setup all images / iframes and then hide that element with css `style="display:none;"` you can then show or hide the relevant images when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Oh excellent, and what if i wanted to add another button called "weather"?

Comment: I'll update the question to show what you need to do to add a third button for 'weather'

Comment: oh okay, thanks a lot for your help. I'll play around with this and get back to you if i need more help :P

Comment: Its not finding my images when I click the buttons

Comment: @lowlyf If you found this answer useful please upvote, if it was the best answer for you / the answer you were looking for please also accept (click the blank tick next to my answer). This will help other users find this question and answer so that it may help them as well. Thanks

Comment: @lowlyf when you run the function from your button you have to make sure you pass the right id into the function for it to find your image. `onclick="chamgeImages('googlemap')"` here googlemap has to be the exact id for the googlemap paragraph where you are setting the content. Please check all your references are correct and match and let me know what error message you are getting.

Comment: I have marked this as the best answer mate. Are these the references correct? `<p align="center"style="font-family:verdana;" id='titleMap'>    Choose a Main Display</p>`
    
`<p align="center"style="font-family:verdana;"id="googlemap"> </p>

<p align="center"id="bommap"></p>`

Comment: Yes but you have not added a `p` element for the weather. I have not included editing "titleMap" in my example but your id's for "googlemap" and "bommap" are correct as long as these are the same in the javascript function and when you call the function from your buttons.

Comment: Ahhh, I have to add p weather for it to work. It works now. You sir, are a legend

Comment: @lowlyf that I very much doubt, but i'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code to : Create a new `<p>` tag which contains the text to display/hide. You need to clear other `<p>` when you want to display a map.

```
  <p id='titleMap'>    Choose a Main Display</p>
    <p align="center"style="font-family:verdana;"id="googlemap">
    </p>
    <p align="center"id="bommap"></p>

    <script>

    function mapFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("bommap").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("titleMap").innerHTMl = "";
    x=document.getElementById("googlemap");  // Find the element
    x.innerHTML='<iframe ...></iframe>'    // Change the content
    }

    function rainFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("googlemap").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("titleMap").innerHTMl = "";
    x=document.getElementById("bommap");    // Find the Element
    x.innerHTML='<img src="http://www.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR663.gif?20130517070843" border="0"     alt="128 km Brisbane (Mt Stapylton) Radar" title="128 km Brisbane (Mt Stapylton) Radar">'
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, How do I make the text display and hide?

Comment: in each function `document.getElementById("titleMap").innerHTMl = "";`  hide the text. You can display it by setting the innerHTML `document.getElementById("titleMap").innerHTMl = "Choose your display";`
If you want hide and display text you can also play with style and visibility :
`document.getElementById("titleMap").style.visibility = "hidden"; // or "visible"`